# Nativescript Angular2 Route Provider

Tags: typescript, angular, nativescript

I am trying to follow the quick start demo of nativescript with angular2. When I come to routers, it started to fail. Error message: **No provider for RouterOutletMap!** Here is my code,

```
main.ts
#############
    import {nativeScriptBootstrap} from "nativescript-angular/application";
    import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
    import {NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NS_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "nativescript-angular/router";
    import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

    nativeScriptBootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

and

```
app.component.ts
    ############


     import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {nativeScriptBootstrap} from "nativescript-angular/application";
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NS_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "nativescript-angular/router";
import {FirstComponent} from "./first.component";
import {SecondComponent} from "./second.component";


@Component({
    selector: 'navigation-test',
    providers: [NS_ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>`
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/first', component: FirstComponent, name: 'First', useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/second', component: SecondComponent, name: 'Second' },
])
export class AppComponent { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a solution in nativescript github issues [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/318)
you should import `NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`, `NS_ROUTER_PROVIDERS` from `"nativescript-angular/router-deprecated/ns-router-deprecated"`

like this:

`import {NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NS_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "nativescript-angular/router-deprecated/ns-router-deprecated";`

and below  I removed unnecessary imports and providers and ...

**main.ts**

```
import {nativeScriptBootstrap} from "nativescript-angular/application";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

nativeScriptBootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {RouteConfig} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NS_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "nativescript-angular/router-deprecated/ns-router-deprecated";
import {FirstComponent} from "./first.component";
import {SecondComponent} from "./second.component";

@Component({
   selector: 'navigation-test',
   directives: [NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
   providers: [NS_ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
   template: `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>`
})
@RouteConfig([
   { path: '/first', component: FirstComponent, name: 'First',      useAsDefault: true },
   { path: '/second', component: SecondComponent, name: 'Second' },
  ])
 export class AppComponent { }
```